# qooxdoo and search engines

Tags: qooxdoo

i am playing around with qooxdoo lately, it is really interresting, but all the examples build up everything from a blank html page, which would end in being the whole site not indexable from a search engine.

Is there a way to build qooxdoo widgets from html source... most important for me would be a table, so i put html code of the table in the page and tell qooxdoo to build the table from the html source, is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

A general approach would be to to make all your "pages" accessible via URLs styled like example.com/#page=x. Then configure your web-server to rewrite to those URLs, so that for example page/x.html is mapped to #page=x. Finally, submit an XML-Sitemap to Google and other search engines.